# Ajax .load method won't load content

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Users are supposed to select the product, and more information appears in a specified div,`<div id="display"></div>` . The clicked element `.thumbnail`and it's child elements html appears in the console, though it doesn't load into `#display` . The first section of the code is working correctly, loading all products into the page form a .JSON file.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row md-btm-padding">
        <div class="sm-btm-padding col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="cat-section light-grey-border sm-padding">
                <div id="display"></div>
            </div>                          
        </div>

        <div class="cat-group">
           <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!--container end-->
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

function loadProducts() {                    
    $.getJSON('products.json')              
    .done( function(data){                      
        products = data.products;
        renderProducts();
    }).fail( function() {                       
        $('#content').html('Sorry! We could not load our products at the moment. Try again later!');
    });
}

loadProducts();                      

function renderProducts() {

    var newContent = '';                               // Build up timetable by
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {      // looping through events
        newContent += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">';
        newContent += '<a class="thumbnail">';
        newContent += '<h4>SKU: <span>' + products[i].product + '</span></h4>';
        newContent += '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + products[i].img + '">';
        newContent += '</a>';
        newContent += '</div>';
    }

    $('#content').html(newContent);
}

//DISPLAY PRODUCT

$('#content').on('click', 'a.thumbnail', function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault();                                     
     var fragment = this;     
     console.log(this);                          


  $('#display').load(fragment);                           

  $('a.current').removeClass('current');       
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

});

Comment: You see the `<div id="display"`? When a user clicks on a thumbnail, I want information on that product to display in `#display`

Comment: `$('#display').load(fragment);` what? ....

Comment: I have confused myself now. I am new to Ajax/JSON. I want to enable users to click on a thumbnail, then a bigger version (img, text) to display in another div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling load

```
$('#display').load(fragment);
```

with a fragment which is pointing to an achor you clicked on. The load method is expecting a url string as the parameter, not a reference to a DOM node.

So if you want to display the content, you want `.html()` or you if you need to fetch more details, you need to reference a url to fetch.

```
$('#display').html(fragment.innerHTML);     
//OR
$('#display').html($(fragment).html());
```

Comment: It is fetching data from a .JSON file. I changed the load method to html, which got the information to display in the `#display`, which is what I wanted, but removed the thumbnail from it's original position

Comment: make a copy... updating

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`load()` expects  string url as first argument. You are trying to pass in `this`.

It's not clear what your intent is , if you have a url available in your json then add `href` to your html string and change to

```
var fragment = this.href;
```